# iOS: Canvas URL error when posting to wall

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-wall

*Please see the 29th December update notes at the bottom of the page.*

Hi I'm doing maintanance work on someone else's iOS project at work (which is kind of soul destroying because they haven't documented their code).

The problem is that after the user logs in, attempting to share a post to the wall always results in

**error 100: "*The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL*".**

I've searched for the past 2 hours and haven't found any results specifically for iOS (but plenty for wordpress, which didn't help)

Any ideas what might be causing this.

**Here's the overseas developer code for posting to the wall:**

```
-(void)uploadPropertyDetailsOnFacebookWall
{


[FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet setWithObjects:FBLoggingBehaviorFBRequests, FBLoggingBehaviorFBURLConnections, nil]];

NSString* photoURL = @"";
NSString *strFullPropertyDetailLink=@"";
if (!kIsListOnce) {
    photoURL = [currentItem objectForKey:@"Photo1FeaturedURL"];
    strFullPropertyDetailLink=[currentItem objectForKey:@"FullDisplayLink"];
}
else {
    strFullPropertyDetailLink=[currentItem objectForKey:@"FullDisplayLink"];
    NSArray* list = [[currentItem objectForKey:@"objects"] objectForKey:@"img_small"];
    ;
    if ([list count] > 0) {
        photoURL = [list objectAtIndex:0];
    }

}

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

NSString *strLinkOfApp=(NSString *)[Utils config:KiTunesstoreAppLink]; //strFullPropertyDetailLink,
NSDictionary *postParams =
[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:


 strFullPropertyDetailLink, @"link",
 photoURL, @"picture",
 [Utils config:kTextAgentName], @"name",
 strAddress, @"caption",
 [currentItem objectForKey:@"Description"], @"description",
 nil];



[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                             parameters:postParams
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error)
 {
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

     NSString *alertText;

     NSLog(@"%@",error);


     if (error) {

         NSDictionary *dict=[error userInfo];
         NSLog(@"%@",dict);

         NSDictionary *dictJSON=[dict objectForKey:@"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"];
         NSDictionary *dictBody=[dictJSON objectForKey:@"body"];
         NSDictionary *dictError=[dictBody objectForKey:@"error"];

         NSString *strCode=[[dictError objectForKey:@"code"] description];

         if([strCode isEqualToString:@"200"])
         {
             alertText = @"You have not authorized the application to perform this publish action";
         }else{
         alertText = [@"An error ocurred: " stringByAppendingString:error.description];
             alertText=[alertText stringByAppendingString: strFullPropertyDetailLink];
         }
     } else {
         alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                      @"Property details has been successfully shared on your Facebook Wall"];

     }
     [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result"
                                 message:alertText
                                delegate:nil
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                       otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
     // Show the result in an alert

 }];

}
```

**Here's the error I keep getting:**

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed(com.facebook.sdk                  error 5.)" UserInfo=0x1d548710 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 100;
        message = "(#100) The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
2013-08-02 12:06:12.806 RealEstate[385:907] {
"com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode" = 400;
"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey" =     {
    body =         {
        error =             {
            code = 100;
            message = "(#100) The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
};
}
```

Please help, I have done more research online since my initial posting, and still can't find the answer.

**Update Dec 17th:**

- I am using SDK 3.1.1. I'd like to avoid having to update, as I'm maintaining someone else's code.
- Using me/feed, in a fbrequestconnection, any additional paramater aside from "message", crashes the app.
- I've also tried linking the app to a test account with settings suggested by other stack overflow users [viewable here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZQoV.png)
- I've also disabled post streaming security

**Other Questions**

- Am I missing something in linking up the app to Facebook?
- Why won’t it detect that the “link” parameter is the same as the canvas url?

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with posting to facebook wall too.

Why don't you use the facebook SDK instead of the API?
There are two ways to post to facebook wall using the SDK

Via [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/)
or
Via [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share-dialog/)

The Feed Dialog is very easy to implement and you can control what you want to post through the parameters you send, the only bad thing is that the parameters are limited.

The Share Dialog uses OpenGraph and requires the user to have the facebook APP installed, you also have to create an action in app developer page in facebook so your app knows what to do with that action. 
The good part is that you can share almost all that you want.

I suggest you check the Feed Dialog if you want a simple facebook share, it's the easiest way.

Edit

```
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%@",domain,TypeName,[object alias]];

    // Put together the dialog parameters

    NSMutableDictionary *params =

    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

     @"TITLE", @"description",

     message, @"link",

     [object image],@"picture",

     nil];

    // Invoke the dialog

    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil

                                       parameters:params

                                          handler:

     ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {

         if (error) {

         // Error launching the dialog or publishing a story.

         //NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");

         } else {

             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {

                 // User clicked the "x" icon

                 //NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");

             } else {

                 // Handle the publish feed callback

                 NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];

                 if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {

                     // User clicked the Cancel button

                     //NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");

                 } else {

                     // User clicked the Share button

                     NSString *msg = @"Partilhado com sucesso";

                     //NSLog(@"%@", msg);

                     // Show the result in an alert

                     [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Aviso"

                                                 message:msg

                                                delegate:nil

                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"

                                       otherButtonTitles:nil]

                      show];

                 }

             }

         }

     }];
```

Comment: I don't have access to feed dialogues, code is using SDK 3.1.1

Comment: I've Eddited the aswer with some code that I've used. check if it's possible to update the sdk, although I believe Feed dialog is available in that version.